# Array length is not changing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think i am making a mistake in pushing api response data into array. it is not reflecting. The length of the array remains 1.

When i get a response from watson api. I am pushing that response into an array. Then I call fetchLogs function again to get next page and push it in the same array. But I am seeing first response only.

I am writing it in a text file when no logs left. I only see first response.

Could any one please guide me. Why value is not being pushed.

```
let nxt_url = '';
const logs = [];

const fetchLogs = async () => {
   let newurl = checkUrl();
   try {
    let response = await axios.get(newurl, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      auth: {
        username: "abc123"
        password: "xyz123"
      }
    });
    if(!isEmpty(response.data.pagination)) {
      nxt_url = response.data.pagination.next_url;
      logs.push(response.data) // here I am pushing
      await fetchLogs();
    } else {
      console.log("No More Logs");
      fs.writeFile("temp.txt", JSON.stringify(logs, null, 2), err => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log("log saved in an array !");
      });
    }
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error.message);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to `await fetchLogs()`

Comment: did, but same result

Comment: `fetchlogs()` is not returning any thing

Comment: I am trying run on my local machine i am getting `401` unauthorized error. Are the 
 credentials provided in code are invalid?

Comment: I know it is not returning anything. Question is why it is not pushing response.data in array?  In else block, i am writing that array value into file.Anyway, I am not good in recursion. Could you please help.

Comment: sorry. i can't share watson credential.

Comment: Try adding for loop based on `response.data.pagination` length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194293/discussion-between-saketh-and-meet-singh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (response.data.pagination.next_url) {
      nxt_url = response.data.pagination.next_url;
      logs.push(response.data); // here I am pushing
      return fetchLogs();
    } else {
      logs.push(response.data);
      console.log(logs.length);
      console.log('No More Logs');
      fs.writeFile('temp.txt', JSON.stringify(logs, null, 2), err => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('log saved in an array !');
      });
    }
```